# Hide product title with WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm on WooCommerce 2.11.

I want to remove the top page title which shows the product name. Here is an example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTqDi.png).

I've tried many solutions offered here (and elsewhere)- and none worked.

I tried adding code to my theme's CSS:

```html
#top div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel {
border: none;
}
```

```html
.summary .product_title.entry-title {
display: none;
}
```

And modifing the functions PHP:

```html
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

None have worked.

Can anyone help with a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .single_product_title {
 display: none;
 }
```

The above worked for me when on your test site.

On a sidenote - tucking away the (supposedly) H1 title isn't something Google likes and will affect your SEO, unless you're going to show the title in some other way?

Comment: Thank you for the help- but the code has not worked (I put it in my theme's custom CSS section). Adding "!important;" did not work either.

Thanks for the SEO tip- I do plan on having an <H1> title where the description is. I just don't like the huge white space the WooCommerce title forces. Thanks

Comment: If there's a way to give your site's or page's url, we could take a look?

Comment: Worked for me- thanks! Is there a quick/easy way to remove the space it leaves?